# Does spacetime experience torsion like a ribbon does?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

Twisting one end of a ribbon causes the ribbon to want to twist back. So if spacetime is connected, and we can fix the ends of spacetime at our observable universe's ends so to speak, is there some analogue to spacetime experiencing tension when planets revolve?

(I am thinking that revolving matter-energy curves or drags spacetime. If the universe were finite, an object couldn't revolve forever if it "dragged" a tiny bit of spacetime around every time it went around. At some point the fabric would pull back or rip. Or if it reaches some maximum, why doesn't space want to "unwind" itself like the ribbon, creating an opposing spin force in the matter? If space just gets "locked" into this dragged/spun state and doesn't fight back, does that mean there's more energy in the curved spacetime itself?)

Comment: The "tension" you're referring to is called [torsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torsion_(mechanics)).

Comment: Hello. I simplified and redid the title and main question to be more concise and clear. Could this be reopened?